# Auto submit form after radio button checked

Tags: jquery

How can I auto submit a form after each radio button group has a checked radio button? Is there something in jQuery that works with the following scenario:

```
<div class="radio-group">
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn1">
  </div>
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="radio-group">
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn2">
  </div>
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Onchange` of radio button, using `each()` function you can check whether the **radio group length** is equal to 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:radio").change(function(e){
  
    var all_answered = true;
    $("input:radio").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0)
        {
            all_answered = false;
            
        }
        
    });
    if(all_answered== true)
    {
  alert('form submit');
    }
    alert(all_answered);
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-group">
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn1"> 1
  </div>
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn1">1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="radio-group">
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn2">2
  </div>
  <div class="radio-option">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn2">2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so i should add the form submit code  in the alert block (form submit) ?.

Comment: @GpAravindan: your right. Just add $('form').submit(); near that alert

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('input[name=radioBtn2]').change(function(){
     if($('input[name=radioBtn2]').is(':checked')){
        $('form').submit();
     }
   });
   $('input[name=radioBtn1]').change(function(){
   if($('input[name=radioBtn1]').is(':checked')){
        $('form').submit();
     }
   });    
  });
```

Comment: This will submit form every time a user clicks radio button. But OP needs submit when __ALL__ groups are checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if all groups have a checked radio button then you can do:

```
// find all groups
var grps = $( ".radio-group" );    
// next we try find a group with a radio that has no checked item
var hasUnchecked = grps.filter(function(idx, el) {
    // if group has radio button that is checked, 
    // we return false, else - return true 
    return $( el ).find("input:checked")? false : true;
});
// finally in hasUnchecked we have `.radio-group` 
// items with no checked radio found
if (!hasUnchecked) {
    // groups with unchecked radio not found
    // submit a form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() { $('.radiobtn').change(function(){ 
    if($('.radio-group [type=radio]:checked').length == 2) 
    {
    $('form').submit();
}
     }); 
     });
```